# using a date in an excel cell reference

Tags: excel-formula

My file is set up to copy from excel workbooks which are created daily and named according to date.
I am currently using a straight forward reference = 'J\analysis\2021-11-14 24 version[workbookname.xlsb]worksheetname'!$A$1 and that works perfectly.
Problem is, my file contains about 20 cells each with the a similar reference. Replacing the file path or part of it with a date reference such as today()-1 would save me the hustle of updating 20 cells with the same date everyday.
Could anyone help me out and show me how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Example using a dummy name, you should be able to adapt for your specific file name

```
="My file name " & TEXT(TODAY()-1,"YYYY-MM-DD") & ".xlsx"
```

Gives you

My file name 2021-11-15.xlsx

The TEXT() function is what you need to convert a date :)

Comment: I tried that and I get the result as My file Name 2021-11-15.xlsx]worksheet'!A1.

Comment: What I am trying to do is make this a cell reference so that instead of My file Name 2021-11-15.xlsx]worksheet'!A1  the result would be the contents of the cell located at My file Name 2021-11-15.xlsx]worksheet'!A1

Comment: Did this with the indirect formula, problem is it only works when the referenced workbook is open, do you know of anyother way around this?

Comment: Thanks for the date thing, I piggybacked on this and added the indirect formula, so atleast this solved one of the issues I had

Comment: I wasn't able to find a way to get the file path and dynamic file name to work.  Do all the files you need to reference have the same format (eg column layout).  If so, you might be able to consolidate them with Power Query and go from there?  Power Query has an option to read in all files from a folder.  You could probably edit the query and filter the files it reads.